# Solidity division question

Tags: solidity

hi folks i'm looking do do the following division function here is an example of the input.

_value / (totalSupply() / _shareSupply);

50000000000000000000 / 110000000000000000000 / 100000000000000000000

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: There is no clear question in this post

Answer (score 1):

Some things you should take into account when doing this:

- Solidity doesn't at the moment have support for floating point arithmetic, so expect rounding
- There may be other ways of achieving the same outcome
- Where possible, try and turn division into multiplication, so that you are not affected by rounding errors

If you have to arrive at this ratio, I would propose the following formula:

`_value * _shareSupply / totalSupply()`.

However, if you are, for example checking if this value is greater than some value `x`, it's better achieved like so:

`_value * _shareSupply > x * totalSupply()`

Do keep potential overflow risks in mind depending on the maximum size of numbers.